# Subscribe to like button in tab page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-like

How is it possible to subscribe to the event (i guess it is done this way) of pressing the Like button in a facebook tab page? ... perhaps using Facebook javascript SDK?

For development i use ASP.NET MVC 3, does it interfere with anything of the Facebook javascript SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that i didn't need to subscribe to this particular event: the tab page is reloaded each time it is liked or disliked. Thus there is the possibility to use the C# SDK for Facebook to retrieve info about the liked status.